# No Update indexes option in Assets

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I have a member group called Admin and it's not seeing the menu options of Update Indexes, External Sources or Settings.
Admin screenshot at the top, SuperAdmin below
[image: Admin login]
[image: SuperAdmin login]
They have access to the Add-Ons, Modules section, and Assets, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Paul, that's available only to superadmins at the moment (Assets 2.2.4), due to security concerns of exposing 3rd party API keys. You can re-index the current folder in Assets by clicking the circular arrow on the top right corner, however that won't index any new folders.

I'll add a config setting to the next version of Assets for this. Meanwhile, if you need a custom fix, hit us up (support@pixelandtonic.com) and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: +1 for support for a custom config override for this, that would be most excellent.